# Haskell define a non-empty list datatype

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have defined a data type like this for representing a 2D point:

```
data Point = Point (Double, Double) deriving (Show)
```

And a data type Curve (curve is a list of points in 2D space that create a curve

```
data Curve  = Curve [Point] deriving (Show)
```

How can I set the Curve datatype to be nonempty? so that it always needs to have at least 1 Point in the list?

Comment: One easy way is `data Curve  = Curve Point [Point]`. Besides, for performance reasons, you could use `newtype` instead of `data` to define `Point`.

Comment: Existing types defined the way @Jubobs suggested: [NonEmpty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.16.2.2/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html), [T](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/non-empty-0.2.1/docs/Data-NonEmpty.html) (haddock warning: Thielemann), [NonEmpty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmpty-0.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html).

Comment: @DanielWagner, why does Henning merit a warning? Is there something wrong with his libraries that I haven't noticed?

Comment: @dfeuer The haddocks are very hard to read because every type is named `T` and every class is named `C`. In code, that's fine, because his style is to import everything qualified (so things look like `NonEmpty.T` or `Ring.C`), but haddock doesn't really deal with that style gracefully, resulting in type signatures that look like `(C a, C b) => T a -> T b -> T -> T` and other such illegible nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Data.List.NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.16.2.2/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) module, in the popular `semigroups` library, implements a non-empty list type, and utility functions for it.

The solution is effectively the same as Cactus' answer, a pair that contains an obligatory first element and then a list for the rest:

```
data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]
```

So Cactus' `Curve` type would be equivalent to `NonEmpty Point`.

Answer (score 1):

The list `[Point]` will always contain 0 or more `Point`s, so if you store an extra one, you get 1 + (0 or more) = 1 or [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition) `Point`s:

```
data Curve = Curve Point [Point]
```